# Why is my first reponse null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, cllocation, nsurlsession

I have a `Location.m` model, which I use to obtain latitude and longitude. When I have those, I call my delegate method which is implemented in my `Foursquare.m` model.

Location.h looks like this:

```
@class Location;

@protocol LocationDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)location:(Location *)loc didFinishFindingLocation:(CLLocation *)location;
@end

@interface Location : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <LocationDelegate> delegate;    
- (void)startLocationManager;

@end
```

Location.m:

```
@implementation Location
{
    CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
    BOOL _locationIsUpdated;
}

- (void)startLocationManager
{
    NSLog(@"In startLocationManager");
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    _locationIsUpdated = NO;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - LocationManager Delegates

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if (locations && _locationIsUpdated == NO) {
        self.location = [locations lastObject];
        NSLog(@"%@", _location);
        _locationIsUpdated = YES;
        [self.delegate location:self didFinishFindingLocation:self.location];
    }

}

@end
```

When the delegate method is called from the Foursquare model, and I NSLog out the response in an array (called self.dataResponse). It always outputs `(null)` first, then all the JSON. Why does that happen? If I NSLog out `dataDictionary` (see code below) directly, the JSON output shows a error-code:400  and nothing is printed. Couple of milliseconds after everything is printed and seems to be working fine...

Here is a picture:
When I log the `dataDictionary`
[image]

Here is the delegate method implemented in Foursquare.m:

```
- (void)location:(Location *)loc didFinishFindingLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    loc.delegate = self;

    self.resultFromResponse = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *search = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=%f,%f&radius=2000&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=%@", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude, kFourdquareAPIKey, fFoursquareSecret, [Foursquare getCurrentDate]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:search];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            self.dataResponse = dataDictionary[@"response"][@"venues"];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.dataResponse);
            for (NSDictionary *venue in self.dataResponse) {
                FSDataFromJSON *data = [[FSDataFromJSON alloc] init];
                data.name = venue[@"name"];
                data.phone = venue[@"phone"];
                data.location = venue[@"location"];
                [self.resultFromResponse addObject:data];
            }
            //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"JSONRequestFinishedLoading" object:nil];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
        }
    }];

    [task resume];
}
```

At the very end, these models is started in my MainViewController:

```
 _location = [[Location alloc] init];
    [_location startLocationManager];

    _foursquare = [[Foursquare alloc] init];
    [_foursquare location:_location didFinishFindingLocation:_location.location];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the last line of code in your question is likely the problem:

```
[_foursquare location:_location didFinishFindingLocation:_location.location];
```

You shouldn't be calling your delegate method explicitly (before the location has been set). Instead, you should be waiting for the `CLLocation` callback to kick it off.

Other thoughts:

- If the `Location` class has a `.location` property, I think that's confusing.
- `Location.m` is not a model, it's the file containing the class implementation. I'd say the `Location` class is a model.
- You could simplify your delegate method as `didFindLocation:(Location *)location` since you can get the `CLLocation` in the method as `location.location`.
- What are the three most important factors in real estate? [`location.location.location`](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_origin_of_the_term_location_location_location)!

Comment: I put all the networking stuff inside if (location){} - that made the error go away. I don't know why that would be necessary though. The location delegate doesn't get called before a location is found anyway - But thanks for the tips :)

Comment: If I don't instantiate the foursquare model, the delegate method doesn't get called for whatever reason..?

Comment: 1. You're explicitly calling the delegate method in the very last line of your post, *outside* of the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` call, where you really want it. 2. *Nobody* generally calls **classes** models. You should probably be idiomatic in your terminology, if you want to be effective in communicating about this stuff. I'd encourage you to truly try to understand what I was trying to communicate to you here, it's free tutoring. :)

Comment: 1. I'm calling my delegate method in locationManager:didUpdateLocations: AND in my viewController, which probably is redundant/wrong. 2. I have two models (one for giving me locations and one for handling to network-requests, so that I in the end can display the data through my views/viewControllers. I don't think I'm calling my classes models or vice versa. 3. I'm doing my best ;)

Comment: @Nilzone- I *want* you to do your best. :) Points: 1. If somebody tells you something is redundant, and you find it is redundant, no need to argue with them about it first, right? 2. "Model" is conceptual, that's your business, but it's beyond the scope of what you are trying to communicate here. "Class" is technical, and that's the kind of thing you are trying to convey here. Muddying it up with nonstandard terminology is just shooting yourself in the foot, ultimately.

Comment: I think I need to change quite a bit. But hey, that's how we learn! Thanks for your help anyways